# C# Datagridview - Turn off AutoGenerateColumns when binding to XML file?

Tags: c#, datagridview, autogeneratecolumn

I am binding an XML file to a `DataGridView`. I don't want the columns to be auto-generated, in fact I want to generate them myself. Is there a way of turning off the auto generating columns feature and be able to programmatically create the columns myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns=false
```

Comment: how do i then assign my xml data to new columns i create?

Comment: DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @ozczecho metioned do `Datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns=false;`

For binding the xml to a DataGridView do:

```
myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataSet.ReadXml("dataSetFriendly.xml");
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet;
myDataGridView.DataMember = "dataSetFriendly";
```

In the designer create various columns and set the `DataPropertyName` to the attribute/property name(s) from the Class that was used to generate the XML.

Please read [DataSet.ReadXml Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx) for more information about loading xml into a dataset.

Other way of binding xml to `Datagridview` is deserializing the xml to a `List<MyClass>` and use it as `BindingSource`.